# Как с помощью регулярных выражений из строки получить цифры / №

Tags: php

Есть строка Приход № 5146 12/12/2018 Имя Перейти как получить =  № 5146 12/12/2018 Имя

```
$str =  ' Приход № 5146 12/12/2018 Имя';               
$number = preg_replace("/[^№ \/ 0-9]/", '', $str);
ответ № 5146 12/12/2018, а имя не получается в конце подставить.
```

Comment: почему бы просто не удалить `Приход ` ?

Answer (score 1):

> *имя не получается в конце подставить*

Если с помощью *preg_replace()*, то шаблон должен захватывать только те символы, которые нужно удалять:

```
$str = ' Приход № 5146 12/12/2018 Имя';               
$str = preg_replace('~.+?(?=№.+)~', '', $str);

echo $str; // № 5146 12/12/2018 Имя
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант без регулярного выражения:

```
$str = ' Приход № 5146 12/12/2018 Имя';     
echo stristr($str, '№');
```